# Since what gradle version is the gradle daemon a thing?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm writing my thesis and I would like to know since what version of gradle have they added the daemon to drastically reduce the build times?

Comment: Please learn how StackOverflow works and [what questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) should be [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The fact that you answered your own question only **two minutes** after you asked it, shows the lack of research effort before asking.

Comment: I have overlooked the answer a few times and couldn't find it, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the official Gradle website. The daemon was added in version 1.0 and was enabled by default since version 3.0.

Comment: Your question asks when it was *added* - which would be V1.0 [Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/1.0/release-notes.html)